# Iterate over Variables for Linear Regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am looking to run Linear Regression on the below data frame.

```
test<-data.frame(abc=c(2.4,3.2,8.9,9.8,10.0,3.2,5.4),
             city1_0=c(5.3,2.6,3,5.4,7.8,4.4,5.5),
             city1_1=c(2.3,5.6,3,2.4,3.6,2.4,6.5),
             city1_2=c(4.2,1.4,2.6,2,6,3.6,2.4),
             city1_3=c(2.4,2.6,9.4,4.6,2.5,1.2,7.5),
             city1_4=c(8.2,4.2,7.6,3.4,1.7,5.2,9.7),
             city2_0=c(4.3,8.6,6,3.7,7.8,4.7,5.8),                                           city2_1=c(5.3,2.6,3,5.4,7.8,4.4,5.5))
```

Dataframe "test" is sample of the data. But original data frame contains 100 columns. I want to create a script for predicting values using linear regression. In this case, I want to build many models with different input variables.

For example, in the given dataframe, **abc** is the y variable. I want to build one model 
city1_1,city1_2,city1_3,city1_4 (leaving city1_0, city2_0). Then other model with city1_2,city1_3,city1_4 (leaving city1_0,city1_1,city2_0,city2_1)
and then 3rd model with input variable city1_3,city1_4 (leaving city1_0,city1_1,city1_2,city2_0,city2_1), and so on.

These all variables are input to the Linear Regression.

This I have to do for 40 dataframes. O/P variable name remains same for every dataframe.

Comment: What's the pattern to the combinations you want to try? A common approach is to paste variable names together as strings and then `lapply(string_formulas, function(form){lm(as.formula(form), data = df})`. That said, a more thorough approach to feature selection like the LASSO may be a better idea.

Comment: @allstaire, Actually, When I am using all the 1 suffixed variables, I don't want to use 0 suffixed variables in my model, and when I am using 2 suffixed variables, I don't want want to use 0's and 1's suffixed variables in my 2nd model and so on. Basically, I have to build many multiples models based on the variables. How to implement this?

Comment: This is an exact repost of an earlier question. You need to do some work to get base code, then ask for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a list of formulas using regular expression, and then `lapply` over this list:

```
# create data
test<-data.frame(abc=c(2.4,3.2,8.9,9.8,10.0,3.2,5.4),
             city1_0=c(5.3,2.6,3,5.4,7.8,4.4,5.5),
             city1_1=c(2.3,5.6,3,2.4,3.6,2.4,6.5),
             city1_2=c(4.2,1.4,2.6,2,6,3.6,2.4),
             city1_3=c(2.4,2.6,9.4,4.6,2.5,1.2,7.5),
             city1_4=c(8.2,4.2,7.6,3.4,1.7,5.2,9.7),
             city2_0=c(4.3,8.6,6,3.7,7.8,4.7,5.8),                                           
             city2_1=c(5.3,2.6,3,5.4,7.8,4.4,5.5))

# create list of formulas
myformulas <- list(as.formula(paste("abc", paste(grep("city1_[123456789]", names(test), value = TRUE), collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ ")),
                   as.formula(paste("abc", paste(grep("city1_[23456789]", names(test), value = TRUE), collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ ")),
                   as.formula(paste("abc", paste(grep("city1_[3456789]", names(test), value = TRUE), collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ ")))

# check formulas
> myformulas
[[1]]
abc ~ city1_1 + city1_2 + city1_3 + city1_4

[[2]]
abc ~ city1_2 + city1_3 + city1_4

[[3]]
abc ~ city1_3 + city1_4


# loop over formulas
mylms <- lapply(myformulas, function(x) lm(x, data = test))


# get output of linear regressions
> mylms
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = x, data = test)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      city1_1      city1_2      city1_3      city1_4  
     5.8987      -0.2480       0.6316       1.1810      -1.0420  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = x, data = test)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      city1_2      city1_3      city1_4  
     4.8903       0.7114       1.1673      -1.0595  


[[3]]

Call:
lm(formula = x, data = test)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)      city1_3      city1_4  
      7.909        1.047       -1.102
```

You could even prespecify the `grep()` patterns and create the formulas with a loop:

```
mygreps <- c("city1_[123456789]", "city1_[23456789]", "city1_[3456789]")

myformulas <- lapply(mygreps, function(x) as.formula(paste("abc", paste(grep(x, names(test), value = TRUE), collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ ")))
```

---

Edit:

You can also just define the value range of the `city` variables and use `paste()` to generate the strings.

Example:

```
myranges <- lapply(1:16, function(x) x:16)
myvars <- paste0("city", 1:10, "_")
```

Then from this, create the formulas with a nested `lapply()` call:

```
myformulas <- lapply(myvars, function(x) lapply(myranges, function(y) as.formula(paste("abc", paste(x, y, sep = "", collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ "))))
```

`myformulas` will now include 10 lists (one for each `city1_` to `city10_`) with 16 formulas in every list (each including a decrementing amount of variables, beginning with all 16, and ending with only `cityX_16`).

Now just loop over `myformulas` to get a list of linear regression output:

```
# loop over formulas
mylms <- lapply(myformulas, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) lm(y, data = test)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I have variable starting from city1_1.....city1_16 till city10_1.......city10_16. How to handle this in this code? Because every time writing city name is not feasible. It will take forever.

Comment: I've edited another version. This creates a list of formulas for all 10 city variables, with 16 formulas each (beginning with all `cityX_1` to `cityX_16` and ending with only `cityX_16` as predictors).

Comment: thank you so much, Lap!!

Comment: You are welcome :)